# Plot a function with very small values, close to zero

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, machine-precision

I want to plot a function with very small values, close to zero, but even though the limit is `-3/2` as `x->0`, I can't get any graphs. So I'm wondering if I could really get any graphs with any modifications in the Plot command options.

```
Limit[15 Integrate[Cos[t^2] - 1, {t, 0, x^ 3}]/x^15, x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(* Ans: -3/2*)
Plot[{15 NIntegrate[(Cos[t^2] - 1), {t, 0, x^3}, MinRecursion -> 4]/x^15, -3/2}, {x, -0.001, 0}]
```

[image]

**Edit:** The function and  series representation is

$\dfrac{15\int_{0}^{x^3}(\cos (t^2)-1)\, dt  }{x^{15}}=-\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{5 x^{12}}{72}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$

Comment: Integrate your function exactly instead of approximately and then use more precision for the plot `z=15*Integrate[(Cos[t^2]-1), {t,0,x^3}]/x^15; Plot[z, {x,-10^-5,10^-5}, WorkingPrecision->128, PlotRange->{-1.6,.2}]` Then reduce the precision to 64 and see that Plot makes a mistake. Who knows what the plot REALLY REALLY looks like.

Comment: "...Who knows what the plot REALLY REALLY looks like...":  So you think there is no way to get the graph?

Comment: Evaluate the integral symbolically, `15 Integrate[Cos[t^2] - 1, {t, 0, x^3}, Assumptions -> x < 0]/x^15`, and then use ``ListPlot[Table[{x, %}, {x, -1.`100, -0.000000001`100, .0001`100}], Joined -> True]``.

Comment: It doesn't work, no graphic